# Oracle SQL - Add 2 numbers, show maximum number and show name from another table

Tags: sql, oracle, inner-join, max

Im trying to query my database and I have a few tables.

First table is Player table. This has PlayerID and FirstName and a bunch of other stuff that isnt relevant to this question.

My other table is experience. This has PlayerID, NatGames and Int Games.

What I am trying to do is, add NatGames and IntGames together and show the highest result. I can do this with a max function like this:

`select max (natgames + intgames) AS "Most Expiercened" from experience;`

This then displayed the highest number when the 2 numbers are added.

Now what I would like to do is show the name of this person which should come from the playerID coming from the Player table.

I have tried for hours and I havent been able to do this. I have something like this but to failure:

```
SELECT Player.Firstname, Experience.Natgames, Experience.Intgames
FROM Player
INNER JOIN Experience
ON Experience.PlayerID = Player.PlayerID
INNER JOIN (
SELECT Experience.PlayerID, MAX(Natgames + IntGames) AS TotalExperience
FROM Experience
GROUP BY Experience.PlayerID
) as TotalExperience
ON Experience.PlayerID = TotalExperience.ID
AND (NatGames + Intgames) = TotalExperience.TotalExperience
;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` to find the row with the highest `NatGames + IntGames`:

```
select  p.Name
,       e.NatGames + e.IntGames
from    (
        select  row_number() over (order by NatGames + IntGames desc) as rn
        ,       PlayerID
        ,       NatGames
        ,       IntGames
        from    Experience
        ) e
join    Players p
on      p.PlayerID = e.PlayerID 
where   e.rn = 1 -- Row #1 when sorted by NatGames + IntGames desc
```